# Convert binary file to a text and vice versa with Erlang

Tags: erlang

There is a binary file 'test.dat'. I need convert it to the text, do some change, and save it as binary again.

I was able to convert to text:

```
erl -noinput -eval 'case file:read_file("test.dat") of {ok, B} -> io:format("~p~n", [binary_to_term(B)]) end.' -run init stop > test.text
```

But I don't have idea, how save text as binary file now?

Answer (score 1):

If `B` is where the binary is, then:

```
file:write_file("new_test.dat", B).
```